# Controlling the ordering of the Extension Object XML file contents

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I'm encountering an issue that when I add new functoids to my map, the references to other functoids in my inline XSLT scripts (ScriptNS1 etc - the general ones provided by the framework) become reordered and as a result it cant find my methods.

Is there a way I can control this file behind without using an XSLT document and controlling the whole thing that way? I'd like to keep the BTM file and control the XML extension file if I can.

Tried the 'obvious' route of selecting it in the options in VS2010 however this gets ignored unless the XSLT document is in use as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, no.  We have not control over the resultant prefixes in the output.  This kind of reshuffling happened to me a couple of times too.

What you can do is add your Assembly to the custom extension xml where you can set your own namespace, which you'd then use in the inline Xsl.  The Map compiler will not alter that.

Custom Extension: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa547368.aspx

Unfortunately, there is a bug in Visual Studio that prevents that value form being saved.  Here's the workaround which does work fine: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/BizTalk-Mapper-Custom-3050cb3e

For similar reasons, I always use the full namespace on nodes generated in inline Xsl also.